# Review Notification still show after all Posts and Answers has been reviewed

Tags: support

I am not sure if this is a new thing in SO, but after I reviewed all First Post and Late Answers, still it shows the number of post and answers unattended? But when I click the link to review, there's no available Post or Answer to review. I find this weird.

Comment: It has been this way for a couple of months or so. I believe it started after a site maintenance event.

Comment: The page you are looking at gets cached. It's not a long cache, but it is enough to put it out from the actual queues by a few minutes sometimes.